# Unmerge merged cell when empty

Tags: vba, excel

i'm trying to get my code right but fail at some point: i have an excel sheet that merges a cell with the one underneath depending on the value that's written in the top cell, but when a value is deleted from a merged cell i'd like the cells to unmerge. 
I try to work with sub to keep my code a bit clean (don't know the proper rules but i try) :

```
Public Sub LetItMerge(Target As Object)  
    If Target.Value = Empty Then  
            Call unMergeCell(Target)          
    Else  
            If (Target.Value = VV Then Call MergeCell(Target)  
    End If  
End Sub
Sub unMergeCell(m As Object)
    m.Resize(1, 1).UnMerge
    m.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
End Sub
Sub MergeCell(n As Object)
        n.Resize(2).Merge                   'merge cells
        n.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter      'center text
        n.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter    'center text
End Sub
```

Comment: The variables in parentheses should probably be `Range` variables, not `Object` variables.  You could probably add the unmerge code to the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: isn't the "Object" necessary when i want to change the borders? I have 12 sheets (one for each month) so i thought it more effective to put it in a module?

Comment: `Target` is a `range` variable and probably should be passed that way, not as an `object`, even though the latter doesn't cause any immediate errors.  You will still need a `Worksheet_Change` event macro on each worksheet. I will revise my answer below to address this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minor tweaks to your code, this appears to be working for me.

The `Worksheet_Change` event fires any time there is a change on the worksheet. Based on the value of the changed cell, it will run either of your `unMerge` or `mergeCell` subroutines.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Use the target.cells(1) since a merged cell.'
    If Target.Cells(1).Value = vbNullString Then
            Call unMergeCell(Target)
    Else
            If Target.Value = VV Then Call MergeCell(Target)
    End If
End Sub

Sub unMergeCell(m As Range)
    m.Resize(1, 1).UnMerge
    m.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
End Sub

Sub MergeCell(n As Range)
        n.Resize(2).Merge                   'merge cells
        n.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter      'center text
        n.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter    'center text
End Sub
```

**Update #1**

If you have multiple worksheets, then you can put the above code in a standard code module, and rename it from `Sub Worksheet_Change(...` to something else like `Sub LetItMerge(Target as Range)`

Then, in each Worksheet's code module, you will still need a `Change` event macro for each worksheet, like this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    LetItMerge Target
End Sub
```

So now, the `_Change` event on each worksheet will trigger this `LetItMerge` routine, which determines which of the `unMerge` or `MergeCells` subroutines to execute.

Comment: thank you - the tweaks were the problem i couldn't figure out.